# How to show depth in image using jQuery or html5, like zazzle.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

[image: as in this image the graphic is slightly curved on ages]

I am working on a project where people can edit their mobile cover and will be able to print there own image with preview here is the example url

[zezzle.com](http://www.zazzle.com/cr/design/pt-casemate_case?customize_it=true&dz=bacbef64-8692-4ef7-8f8d-b2184b95d273)

I have no idea how is it working, need help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As an architect before I enter the web programming field..
I can tell you that somethings sometimes need to optical illusions .. the picture is not bent . 
I think of my work during the short period in the programming field to tell you that can not bend the image .. 
**Short idea** .. is to put the picture down of  mobile cover image and give some opacity and effects to the place which will appear the image in .. you will got what I trying to say in this example

[**SEE That**](http://jsfiddle.net/c9unnk5z/1/) `Hope it will help`